# Amazon Redshift: Is there a machine-friendly method to find slow queries?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm looking to report slow queries (say, >3s) in Redshift to an external monitoring service.

Is there a machine-friendly way (i.e. not the Web UI) of spotting slow queries? For example, Mongo provides a slow query collection and MySQL provides a slow query log. Does Amazon provide something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Queries longer than N seconds in last 1 hour
SELECT u.usename
     , q.database
     , q.query
     , q.querytxt
     , DATEDIFF(second, q.starttime, q.endtime) run_time
FROM stl_query q
JOIN pg_user   u
  ON q.userid = u.usesysid
WHERE database = 'production'
  AND DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime) > 100
  AND starttime BETWEEN ( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1 hour' )
                     --'2016-03-10 13:10:16.270964'
                    AND ( SYSDATE )
                     --'2016-03-10 14:10:16.270964'
;
```

I think 3 seconds is too low for a threshold but YMMV.